# Cannot insert data to table

Tags: mysql, insert

I am trying to insert data into a table using insert.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_products (user_id,productkey,listitemname,itemdescription
      ,thumbnail,rollover,itemfile,themepreview1,themepreview2,themepreview3
      ,themepreview4,categoryname,sub_category_id,browsercompatiable,filesinclude
      ,noofcolumns,layout,demourl,itemtags,create_date,update_date,license_number) 
VALUES (117,'395cb2e171ac','Baby','This is baby'
      ,'a4fb673be7b5','d6232cad4955','e3fe02d02c82','dc7067dffd0a','72f48e9a9585'
      ,'35b016bf135c','6e36d212f3c0','9',51,'ie8,','ie8,',1,1,'http://asdsaf.com'
      ,'rwreewr','2012-06-30','2012-06-30','1565-5827-7289-918')
```

But data is not inserted and MySQL shows the following error:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`wwwwdmar_orangedoor`.`tbl_products`, CONSTRAINT
>   `tbl_products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryname`) REFERENCES
>   `tbl_sub_categories` (`sub_category_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)

Comment: What does `select * from tbl_sub_categories where sub_category = 51` return? The error is as it says. You have a foreign key constraint that's failing.

Comment: It shows "#1054 - Unknown column 'sub_category' in 'where clause''

Comment: How can  I avoid this problem ?

Comment: sorry the query should have been `where sub_category_id = 51`

Comment: It shows a row as 51 9    Wordpress  Templateswptemp   1

Comment: Could you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Try `select * from tbl_sub_categories where sub_category_id = 51` (or try to find if there is a something with id `51` in table `tbl_sub_categories`.

Comment: Yes after executing the query Iam getting a row as "  51 , 9 , Wordpress, Templateswptemp, 1

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have a foreign key on `tbl_products` on the column `categoryname`. This references the column `sub_category_id` in `tbl_sub_categories`.

This stated relationship implies that you *must* have the value you're inserting for `categoryname` (`'9'`) in the column `sub_category_id` of the `tbl_sub_categories`. It obviously does not exist. Should that `9` really be a string?

Without a lot more information it's technically impossible to help you but here goes:

There are two possibilities:

#### Hypothesis 1

You have the column `categoryname` in `tbl_sub_categories` and the name you're inserting is directly related to the `sub_category_id` you're also inserting (`51`).

Solution 1
Remove the column `categoryname` from `tbl_products`. There's no need for it to be there in a properly normalised database. Change the foreign key to be a constraint on the column `sub_category_id` as this is what you seem to be looking up.

Solution 2
Change the foreign key to be on both `categoryname` *and* `sub_category_id`. This is to stop you from inserting values that don't match the referencing columns.

#### Hypothesis 2

You have a separate table called something like `tbl_categories`. In this case, you need to reference this table not `tbl_sub_categories` in your foreign key.